Bulk Fix Message Template Should be Compile Time Constant - Rider
I've inherited a codebase that didn't use ILogger correctly and has interpolation in almost all of its logging.
I would have sworn Rider used to be able to bulk-fix this but it doesn't seem to be able to anymore.
Is there a quick way to fix all of these solution wide?

You may want to use the plugin below:
Structured Logging
However, it is still lacking the bulk feature. Hence, I would also recommend contacting plugin's maintainer using the link:
https://github.com/olsh/resharper-structured-logging

https://github.com/olsh/resharper-structured-logging/issues/121 - issue raised
